# category group when use template-driven and reactive forms angular 9 single API at category sub category?

Tags: angular

i am using angular 9 and i have category group, category and sub category single API in how to manage below data based on reactive form angular checkbox multiple.

Category group and category, sub category data on single API

```
async getAllCategorySubCategoryAndGroupCategoryDetail(): Promise<CategoryDetails[]> {
    try {
            let categoryGroupQuery = `SELECT shrt_category_groups.id as categoryGroupId, 
                                            shrt_category_groups.category_group_name as categoryGroupName 
                                      FROM shrt_category_groups`;
            let categoryGroupList = await pool.query(categoryGroupQuery);

            if (categoryGroupList.length > 0) {
                    let categoryListQuery = `SELECT shrt_categories.id as categoryId,
                                                  shrt_categories.category_name as categoryName,
                                                  shrt_categories.category_image as categoryImage,
                                                  shrt_categories.category_group_id as categoryGroupId
                                             FROM shrt_categories`;

                    let categoryList = await pool.query(categoryListQuery);
                    let subcategoryQuery = `SELECT shrt_sub_categories.id as subCategoryId,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.sub_category_name as subCategoryName,
                                                   shrt_sub_categories.category_id as categoryId 
                                            FROM shrt_sub_categories`;

                    let subCategoryList = await pool.query(subcategoryQuery);
                 
                    const getCategory = (categoryGroupId:any) =>{
                      return categoryList.filter((cat:any) => cat.categoryGroupId == categoryGroupId)
                    }
                    
                    const getSubCategory = (categoryId:any) =>{
                      return subCategoryList.filter((subCategory:any) => subCategory.categoryId == categoryId)
                    }
  
                    let mergeData = categoryGroupList.map((catG:any) => {
                      return { ...catG, 
                            category: getCategory(catG.categoryGroupId).map((cat) => {
                              return { ...cat,
                                  subCategory: getSubCategory(cat.categoryId)
                               }
                            })
                      }
                    })
                    return mergeData;
              }else{
                 return categoryGroupList;
            }
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
  }
```

Comment: Template Driven Forms Features

Easy to use
Suitable for simple scenarios and fails for complex scenarios
Similar to AngularJS
Two way data binding(using [(NgModel)] syntax)
Minimal component code
Automatic track of the form and its data(handled by Angular)
Unit testing is another challenge

Comment: Reactive Forms Features

More flexible, but needs a lot of practice
Handles any complex scenarios
No data binding is done (immutable data model preferred by most developers)
More component code and less HTML markup
Reactive transformations can be made possible such as
Handling a event based on a debounce time
Handling events when the components are distinct until changed
Adding elements dynamically
Easier unit testing